# MonoTouch SIGABRT "Ran out of trampolines of type 2" error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, trampolines

I get a SIGABRT / ran out of trampolines error when running my MonoTouch app on a native device (iPad).

This happens pretty early in my app - I'm constructing a section using MonoTouch.Dialog.

```
        ItemTypeRadio = new RootElement ("Type", new RadioGroup (0))
        {
            new Section ()
            {
                from it in App.ViewModel.ItemTypes
                    select (Element) new RadioElement (it.Name)
            }
        };
```

Is there a compiler setting for increasing the number of trampolines?

How do I profile this and find out why my app is running out?

> Ran out of trampolines of type 2 in
>   '/private/var/mobile/Applications/9A5EE6EB-CAB8-404E-AF2F-E6571C1AC164/iphone.app/mscorlib.dll'
>   (128)
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable/c__Iterator1D`2.MoveNext
>   () <0x000a7>   at MonoTouch.Dialog.Section.AddAll
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
>   [0x00020] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/MonoTouch.Dialog/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs:2006
>   at MonoTouch.Dialog.Section.Add
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/MonoTouch.Dialog/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs:2019
>   at BuiltSteady.Zaplify.Devices.IPhone.AddPage.ViewDidAppear (bool)
>   [0x000d6] in
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/source/devices/ios/iphone/AddPage.cs:65   at
>   (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00042]
>   in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
>   at BuiltSteady.Zaplify.Devices.IPhone.Application.Main (string[])
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/source/devices/ios/iphone/Main.cs:16   at
>   (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
> 0   zaplifyiphone                       0x00ab0334
>   mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 280  1   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00ad3088 sigabrt_signal_handler + 180   2   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x34f80539 _sigtramp + 48     3   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x34f75f5b pthread_kill + 54  4   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x34f6efeb abort + 94     5   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b8c138 monoeg_g_logv + 152    6   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b8c1a8 monoeg_g_log + 32  7   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00aa2454 get_numerous_trampoline + 152  8   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00aa2898 mono_aot_get_imt_thunk + 56    9   zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b459b4 initialize_imt_slot + 112  10  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b46d9c build_imt_slots + 1124     11  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b46f04 mono_vtable_build_imt_slot + 120   12  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00ab3024 mono_convert_imt_slot_to_vtable_slot + 292     13 
>   zaplifyiphone                       0x00ab329c common_call_trampoline
>   + 284     14  zaplifyiphone                       0x00ab17a8 mono_vcall_trampoline + 228  15  zaplifyiphone
>   0x009addb0 generic_trampoline_vcall + 136     16  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00011ee0
>   MonoTouch_Dialog_Section_AddAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_MonoTouch_Dialog_Element
>   + 188     17  zaplifyiphone                       0x00011f68 MonoTouch_Dialog_Section_Add_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_MonoTouch_Dialog_Element + 36  18  zaplifyiphone                       0x00293f0c BuiltSteady_Zaplify_Devices_IPhone_AddPage_ViewDidAppear_bool + 2068
>     19  zaplifyiphone                       0x00968774
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 200     20  zaplifyiphone                       0x00a9c980 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1644   21  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b44e00 mono_runtime_invoke + 128  22  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00ba1518 monotouch_trampoline + 3228    23  UIKit
>   0x351ab6b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
>     24  UIKit                               0x35205269
>   -[UITabBarController viewDidAppear:] + 100    25  UIKit                               0x351ab6b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
>     26  UIKit                               0x351d9115 -[UIViewController
>   _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 56    27  UIKit                               0x35177e3f _afterCACommitHandler + 174  28  CoreFoundation
>   0x340d0b4b
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 18    29  CoreFoundation                      0x340ced87 **CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 258     30  CoreFoundation                      0x340cf0e1 __CFRunLoopRun + 760     31  CoreFoundation                      0x340524dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300   32  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x340523a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104   33  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x35c92fcd GSEventRunModal + 156  34  UIKit
>
>   0x35197743 UIApplicationMain + 1090   35  zaplifyiphone
>
>   0x004d4ba4
>   wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string**_intptr_intptr
>   + 240     36  zaplifyiphone                       0x00277900 BuiltSteady_Zaplify_Devices_IPhone_Application_Main_string__ + 152   37
>   zaplifyiphone                       0x00968774
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 200     38  zaplifyiphone                       0x00a9c980 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1644   39  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b44e00 mono_runtime_invoke + 128  40  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b490ac mono_runtime_exec_main + 436   41  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00b4dd20 mono_runtime_run_main + 756    42  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00aa0d08 mono_jit_exec + 140    43  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00a98f18 main + 2156    44  zaplifyiphone
>   0x00002ff4 start + 52

Comment: I ended up resolving this by going to the project options :: Build :: iPhone Build :: (config debug / platform iPhone) :: Additional mtouch arguments

and adding the following option:

-aot "nimt-trampolines=512"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by going to the project options :: Build :: iPhone Build :: (config debug / platform iPhone) :: Additional mtouch arguments

and adding the following option:

-aot "nimt-trampolines=512"

Answer (score 2):

You should copy-paste your comment into an answer and mark this question as answered (it's ok to answer our own question on stackoverflow) as it will help other people looking for the same issue.

You likely find out about this page while looking for this:
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_2

I modified Mono's runtime (used in MonoTouch) to print this URL when hitting this condition (type 0, 1 or 2). Hopefully this will make it a bit faster to solve this for other people.

Comment: Thanks yet again Sebastien :-)