# App download with webclient not working on device but work on emulator, monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, webclient

I'm downloading json data in my monotouch iphone application by webclient. and using json.NET 4.0 R3 for MonoTouch for parsing json data.
Every thing is right on emulator but on when I create a ad-hoc api file and install it on the iphone it does not work.
I have not device on my hand to debug it and find the errors. can any body help me from what may be the diffrent on emulator and device?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how it doesn't work? How far does the app get? Do you have any code samples to share? Do you get any kind of stack trace or error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not from webclient. Please consider on your codes for parsing json by  json.NET 4.0 R3 for MonoTouch. It is better that use JSON.Net componnet that xamrin himself published.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is your issue without further information, but I know I ran into an issue with my app where it worked fine in the simulator but failed on the device. My issue was because of trampolines. I had to increase mine when running on a device. Here is an example of this problem: [MonoTouch SIGABRT "Ran out of trampolines of type 2" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354391/monotouch-sigabrt-ran-out-of-trampolines-of-type-2-error)

**EDIT**
I had that issue (where the app wouldn't download) also with my in-house deployment. Are you using the correct certificate to sign the app for distribution? You need to make sure that you are using a Distribution certificate. You need to make sure you have a certificate here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action?type=distribution and a provisioning profile here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production.

Have you connected a physical device (provisioned for development) for debugging and made sure that it correctly works on the device? This needs to be your first step. If *this* works, then the issue is likely a certificate/provisioning profile problem and has nothing to do with MonoTouch.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After the app starts to download it takes a little. about 1-2 seconds. and then show the alert dialog that i sid it to show when download failed